# Cannot use import.meta outside a module. Vite testing

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, vite

I'm using vite and jest for testing. When i run my tests i get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uEIJ.png)

This is my .babelrc file [babelrc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMxZz.png)

and this my vite.config [vite config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VK4xu.png)

Does anyone have a solution for this? I've searched and didn't find any answer

**UPDATE:**
I added this on babel.config.js

```js
//babel.config.js

module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      { useBuiltIns: 'entry', corejs: '2', targets: { node: 'current' } },
    ],
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
  plugins: [
    function () {
      return {
        visitor: {
          MetaProperty(path) {
            path.replaceWithSourceString('process')
          },
        },
      }
    },
  ],
}
```

But now i'm getting this error

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKDlX.png)

Comment: Please move your answer text from the question to an answer box, and accept your own answer. This will help others that encounter the same problem.

Comment: This did not work for me